# Delete row from cursor source SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cursor, delete-row

I have a SQL Server 2005 cursor operating over a table variable called `@workingSet`.

Some times rows can be related and in this case I process the row I have fetched and the related rows at the same time. I then remove the related records from `@workingset` as I don't need to process then in the loop.

In a `@workingSet` with 7 rows, the first two are related so when I process 1 I also process 2. I remove row 2 from the cursor source (`@workingSet`) and then fetch next. The problem is it returns the second row in `@workingset` (the one I deleted on the previous iteration).

I was of the impression that this could be done i.e. deleting an item from a source that a cursor operates on and it will honour the delete in subsequent fetches.

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing?? The **best** option would be to eliminate the cursor altogether - which is possible in at least 90% of all cases...

Comment: Thanks and yes you're right .. and I'm still not convinced the cursor is needed but was more interested in knowing that it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be that the table variable that is being used as the source of the cursor needs to have a primary key. I've added this and all works correctly.

Comment: The table in my answer doesn't have a PK and reflects the results of the `DELETE` correctly.

Comment: Hi .. yes I was able to do a proof of concept without the PK and it worked correctly. I don't know why in the other case it requires it.

Comment: Did you have some other cursor options set?

Comment: Hi martin .. no .. no cursor options .. defaults all the way. I;m not convinced this is the answer which is why I've not marked it.

Comment: Think I've found the explanation. You need a dynamic cursor to have the changes in the source table reflected in the cursor fetch. You were getting an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190641.aspx) to a `keyset` or `static` cursor. Possibly as you were ordering by an unindexed column. Is there an `ORDER BY` in your query on the PK column? I get the same behaviour in the query in my answer if I add an `ORDER BY C` to the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

Not massively familiar with cursors but from a quick test this end you need to avoid declaring the cursor with the `STATIC` or `KEYSET` options then the changes to the underlying table are reflected in the cursor.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @WorkingTable TABLE(C int)

INSERT INTO @WorkingTable VALUES (1),(2),(3)

DECLARE @C int

DECLARE wt_cursor CURSOR 
DYNAMIC /*Or left blank but not STATIC or KEYSET*/
FOR 
SELECT C
FROM @WorkingTable

OPEN wt_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM wt_cursor 
INTO @C

DELETE FROM @WorkingTable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @C;


    FETCH NEXT FROM wt_cursor 
    INTO @C;
END
CLOSE wt_cursor;
DEALLOCATE wt_cursor;
```

Comment: Thanks .. yes the cursor was not declared with STATIC or KEYSET.

Comment: @Simon - What do you get when you run the code in my answer but delete the `DYNAMIC` option? For me it just returns `1` not `1,2,3`